# .closest().next(.class) not reaching intended div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing an interactive novel where you get presented with choices that develop you character and the story progression.

I'm trying to figure out why my jQuery doesn't select the correct class using `.closest().next(.class)` but it won't read past the first sibling even though the class does not match.

I've tried changing `.next()` to `.siblings` and that seems to work, except it targets every div with the intended class, and I want to select only the following one in the document.

```
<div class="page" id="p1">
    <header class="chapter-header">
        <h1>PROLOGUE</h1>
        <p>Fear what is and what is not<br> Bravery without fear is but<br> triumpfant stupidity<br></p>
        <p>So fear what is and what is not<br> Then fight fiercely for what could be</p>
    </header>

    <div class="text-section">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, nesciunt!</p>
        <ul class="choice-display" id="choice-display-1">
            <li class="c-btn btn sth-btn c-btn-1">Choice 1</li>
            <li class="c-btn btn pre-btn c-btn-2">Choice 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="c-1 text-section hidden">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, vero?</p>
        <p class="next chapter-p1">Next Page</p>
    </div>

    <div class="c-2 text-section hidden">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, ea!</p>
        <p class="next">Next Page</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".c-btn-1").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".c-1").show('medium');
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".c-1").addClass('active');
});

$(".c-btn-2").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".c-2").show('medium');
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".c-2").addClass('active');
});

$(".c-btn-3").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".c-3").show('medium');
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".c-3").addClass('active');
});

$(".c-btn-4").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".c-4").show('medium');
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".c-4").addClass('active');
});

$(".cp-btn").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".choice-plus").show('medium');
        $(this).closest(".text-section").next(".choice-plus").addClass('active');
});
```

I expect the outcome of c-btn-1 to select the next c-1 in the file and showing it, while c-btn-2 does the same to c-2 and so on.

The problem is that the code wont read past c-1, so c-btn-1 works as expected, but c-btn-2 - 4 can't find their intended elements.

I know the button works because other functions run as expected, it's something wrong with the selecting of the correct sibling.

Comment: Definition of `next()` is *next sibling*. Using  a selector in `next()` just adds an additional filter in case the next sibling isn't that class

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use something like `.siblings`.

Also you can make your code a bit "smarter":

```
$("[class^='c-btn']").click(function() {
  var lc = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
  lc = lc.replace('-btn','');
  $(this).closest(".text-section").siblings("." + lc).show('medium');
  $(this).closest(".text-section").siblings("." + lc).addClass('active');
});
```

**demo**

```js
$("[class^='c-btn']").click(function() {
  var lc = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
  lc = lc.replace('-btn','');
  $(this).closest(".text-section").siblings("." + lc).show('medium');
  $(this).closest(".text-section").siblings("." + lc).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.c-1,.c-2{
display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page" id="p1">
  <header class="chapter-header">
    <h1>PROLOGUE</h1>
    <p>Fear what is and what is not<br> Bravery without fear is but<br> triumpfant stupidity<br></p>
    <p>So fear what is and what is not<br> Then fight fiercely for what could be</p>
  </header>


  <div class="text-section">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, nesciunt!</p>


    <ul class="choice-display" id="choice-display-1">
      <li class="c-btn btn sth-btn c-btn-1">Choice 1</li>
      <li class="c-btn btn pre-btn c-btn-2">Choice 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="c-1 text-section hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, vero?</p>
    <p class="next chapter-p1">Next Page</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c-2 text-section hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, ea!</p>
    <p class="next">Next Page</p>
  </div>
</div>
```